Sympy parametric plot in polar coordinates
I want to plot the parametrization r2=4 cos(t). From 0 to 2π for t this should give me two lobes, symmetrically placed around the y-axis, but I can only get one in sympy due to the square root.
import sympy as sp
r, t = sp.symbols('r t')

r = sp.sqrt(4 * sp.cos(t))

x = r * sp.cos(t)
y = r * sp.sin(t)

sp.plot_parametric((x,y), (t, - sp.pi/2, sp.pi/2), aspect_ratio = (1,1),size=(4,4),axis_center = (0,0))


How do I get its mirror lobe?

If you start with r2=4 cos(t), then you have two solutions for r:

r1 = sp.sqrt(4 * sp.cos(t))
r2 = -sp.sqrt(4 * sp.cos(t))

You want to plot them both:
import sympy as sp
r, t = sp.symbols('r t')

r1 = sp.sqrt(4 * sp.cos(t))
r2 = -sp.sqrt(4 * sp.cos(t))

def to_polar(r):
    x = r * sp.cos(t)
    y = r * sp.sin(t)
    return x, y

sp.plot_parametric(
    to_polar(r1),
    to_polar(r2),
    (t, - sp.pi/2, sp.pi/2), aspect_ratio = (1,1),size=(4,4),axis_center = (0,0))


EDIT to satisfy comment: SymPy doesn't have a plus/minus object. Hence, if you don't want to manually code the expressions, you could write your original equation in r, solve it for r, and loop over the solution to convert them to polar:
r = sp.symbols("r")
eq = sp.Eq(r**2, 4 * sp.cos(t))
sol = sp.solve(eq, r)
polar_sol = [to_polar(s) for s in sol]
sp.plot_parametric(*polar_sol, (t, - sp.pi/2, sp.pi/2), aspect_ratio = (1,1),size=(4,4),axis_center = (0,0))


I was hoping for something neater in which I didn't have to specify both solutions directly. Maybe a ± operator within sympy.

Edited answer to satisfy your request.

Link to the long lasting issue where plus/minus object is requested: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/5305
